# What does it mean to say that a formal theory is recursive

Tags: first-order-logic, decidability

The wikipedia article on Formal Theories states that

"A formal system is said to be recursive (i.e. effective) or recursively enumerable if the set of axioms and the set of inference rules are decidable sets or semidecidable sets, respectively."

Does this mean that that the set of theorems of a formal theory is recursive (i.e. decidable) if the sets of its axioms and inference rules are decidable? That doesn't seem right---the sets of axioms and inference rules of FOL are decidable, but theoremhood isn't.

Comment: The set of axioms is required to be finite or at least decidable, i.e., there must be an algorithm which enables one to decide whether a given statement is an axiom or not. If this condition is satisfied, the theory is called “recursively axiomatizable”, or, simply, "axiomatizable”. The rules of inference are also effective operations, such that it can always be decided whether one has a legitimate application of a rule of inference at hand. Consequently, it is also possible to decide for any given finite sequence of formulas, whether it constitutes a derivation (or proof) in the system.

Comment: A logical system is [decidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidability_(logic)) if there is an effective method for determining whether arbitrary formulas are theorems of the logical system. For example, propositional logic is decidable, because the truth-table method can be used to determine whether an arbitrary propositional formula is logically valid.

Comment: The two are not the same: in the second case we have a tool that, given a formula, answer Y/N to the question: is it valid (i.e. a theorem)? In the first case we can only check, given a sequence of formulas, if it is a correct derivation. In case Y, the end-formula is a theorem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are confounding two distinct yet related notions of decidability here. The first has to do with *computability* and the second with *completeness*. If the set of axioms and rules of inference for a formal theory are decidable in the first sense, then there exists a finite procedure by which one can determine whether a sentence in the formal language is indeed an axiom of the theory, or whether it has been obtained via an application of one of the rules of inference. Hence one can effectively decide (i.e., compute) whether a finite list of sentences is a valid derivation of a theorem.

To assert that a theory is decidable in the second sense (i.e., completeness) is to say that for any given sentence $\varphi$ in the formal language, either $\varphi$ or $\neg \varphi$ can be derived in a finite number of steps from the axioms of the theory. The First Incompleteness Theorem tells us that any consistent formal theory that extends Robinson arithmetic is undecidable in the sense of completeness. That is, there exist sentences $\varphi$ in the language of arithmetic without any formal proof of either $\varphi$ or $\neg \varphi$. But these formal theories of arithmetic are nonetheless decidable in the earlier sense of having a recursive set of axioms and rules of inference.

Comment: I've never heard of decidability in the sense of completeness. The wiki article seems to suggest that decidability of whether a certain sequence is a derivation in the formal system implies the decidability  (in your first sense---computability) of theoremhood of the system. That is what I am questioning. Seems to me FOL is a counter-example

Comment: @saulkripke321 See David Hilbert's *Entscheidungsproblem* (translated as "decision problem") and Alan Turing's landmark 1936 paper "On computable numbers, with an application to the Entscheidungsproblem."

Comment: @saulkripke321 Note that it is possible to have a computably enumerable set $A$ whose elements can be listed as $a_1, a_2, a_3,..$ but such that no finite procedure (i.e., algorithm) exists to determine whether $a \in A$ for a given $a$. In first-order logic, with a recursive set of axioms and rules of inference, the set of theorems is computably enumerable, but it is not necessarily decidable (i.e., computable) whether a given sentence in the formal language belongs to this set.